# Android @IntDef a Local Variable Example

Tags: android, annotations

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html

I'm looking for an example how to define a local variable.

I see how to create a function return, a member variable, a function parameter, but no example to assign a local variable using the Android annotated element @IntDef.

Thanks

UPDATE

Here's one example of what is not working. Does this have something to do with where to put the @Retention? I don't understand how the compiler knows what to apply the Retention Policy to. Is this a global setting?

```
int foobar() {
        @IntDef({
                ItemType.TYPE1,
                ItemType.TYPE2
        })
        @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
        @interface ItemType {
            int TYPE1 = 0;
            int TYPE2 = 1;
        }


        @ItemType int type = TYPE1;
...
}
```

Another example that doesn't work for me:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    final @View.MeasureSpec.MeasureSpecMode int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

...
```

Comment: In case you want to use `@IntDef` to avoid Enums - [you might want to reconsider](https://publicobject.com/2015/09/30/enumsmatter/ "AKA #enumsmatter"). This is an optimization that is done by proguard anyway, so no need to bother yourself with it if it hurts your productivity and/or makes your code less readable.

Answer (score 3):

```
@IntDef({
  ItemType.TYPE1,
  ItemType.TYPE2
})
public @interface ItemType {
  int TYPE1 = 0;
  int TYPE2 = 1;
}

// use it in global variable like
@ItemType
private int type;

// use it in local variable like
public void add(@ItemType int type){

}
```

Comment: @ItemType private int type; - should this have the "private"? I'm getting an error for that.